# Can I AutoGenerateColumns inside a DataGrid, based on a list inside ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm attempting to create a dynamic log viewer. I currently have three classes:

```
public class SystemLogEntry
{
    public ObservableCollection<SystemLogRowEntity> LogEntries { get; set; }
    public SystemLogEntry(){LogEntries = new ObservableCollection<SystemLogRowEntity>();}
}

public class SystemLogRowEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<LogDetailsEntity> Name { get; set; }
}
public class LogDetailsEntity
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

My DataGrid Code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

I also have some initialization code:

```
private SystemLogEntry systemLog = new SystemLogEntry();
```

```
systemLog.LogEntries.Add(new SystemLogRowEntity
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = new List<LogDetailsEntity>
    {
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Name", Details = "SQL Report"},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Type", Details = "Message"},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Time", Details = "15:00"},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Date", Details = "01/01/2019"},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Details", Details = "The SQL Report completed successfully."}
    }
});
systemLog.LogEntries.Add(new SystemLogRowEntity
{
    Id = 2,
    Name = new List<LogDetailsEntity>
    {
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Name", Details = "SQL Report"},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Type", Details = "Error"},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Time", Details = "15:01"},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Date", Details = "01/01/2019"},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Details", Details = "The SQL Report failed catastrophically."},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "Thread", Details = "10250"},
        new LogDetailsEntity {Header = "User", Details = "System"}
    }
});


MainDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
MainDataGrid.DataContext = systemLog;
MainDataGrid.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        Source = systemLog.LogEntries,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    });
```

I would like each item inside LogDetailsEntity to appear as a column header (with associated "details" as the content). However I always just receive "collection" on my DataGrid output.

Comment: You'd have to write code that generates the columns. You could wrap that code in a behavior/attached property and make it look like "auto generation" in the XAML. Another option would be to recreate your data in a `DataTable`, with those column names, and use that as the ItemsSource.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ah, I was wondering if perhaps it was beyond scope of what AutoGenerate could handle. I'll take a look into using a `DataTable` and building what I need around that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from @EdPlunkett, I solved this using a DataTable as the ItemsSource.

```
DataTable logDataTable = new DataTable();

for (var index = 0; index < systemLog.LogEntries.Count; index++)
{
    var entry = systemLog.LogEntries[index];
    foreach (var logDetailsEntity in entry.Name)
    {
        if (logDataTable.Columns.Contains(logDetailsEntity.Header)) continue;
        logDataTable.Columns.Add(logDetailsEntity.Header);
    }
    logDataTable.Rows.Add();
    foreach (var logDetailsEntity in entry.Name)
    {
        logDataTable.Rows[index][logDetailsEntity.Header] = logDetailsEntity.Details;
    }
}
MainDataGrid.ItemsSource = logDataTable.DefaultView;
```